# Swift array: fatal error index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to get an animation to work in Swift but I get an error that says:

> fatal error Index out of range

Here is the code I am using:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var Player = SKSpriteNode()
    var TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var TextureArray = [SKTexture]()

    override func didMove( to view: SKView) {

        TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "images")

        for i in 1...TextureAtlas.textureNames.count{

            var Name = "front_\(i).png"
            TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
        }

        Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0] as! String)

        Player.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 150)
        Player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width, y: self.size.height)
        self.addChild(Player)

        backgroundColor = (UIColor.cyan())
    }

    func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        Player.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: TextureArray, timePerFrame: 1.5)))
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Which line gives you the index of out bounds error?

Comment: Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0] as! String) seems to be the problem

Comment: Shot in the dark, but are your atlas images named starting with 0 or 1?  Referring to this line: `i in 1...TextureAtlas.textureNames.count`, which would be `i in 0..<TextureAtlas.textureNames.count` if starting with 0.

Comment: Always check if the index exists if you aren't 100% certain it does and then consider adding a mechanism that converts out-of-bounds indices into in-bounds indices. For instance, if the index doesn't exist because the integer is too high, use the last index in the array, and if the index doesn't exist because the integer is too low, use 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextureAtlas.textureNames` is empty when you call `Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0] as! String)`. The crash happens when you try to pull something out of an empty array. If this is something that should never be empty, then you need to figure out why it is empty and fix it. Otherwise, you can default to a blank string in-line:

```
Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0] as? String ?? "")
```